# mongoose text search not returning results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a simple text search on a combined index.

Here is my mongoose model:

```
// models/user.js
// load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');



// define the schema for our user model
var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    globalinfo       : {
        ownerobjectid       : String,
        name                : String,
        desc                : String,      
        startdate           : Date,
        enddate             : Date,
        price               : Number,
        status              : String,
        statuscss           : String,
        dateadded           : Date,
        locationline1       : String,
        locationline2       : String,
        locationline3       : String,
        locationtown        : String,
        locationpostcode    : String,
        locationlatitude    : Number,
        locationlongitude   : Number,
        termsapprove        : Boolean,
        friendlyurl         : String,
        itemsearchinfo      : String,
    }
});


itemSchema.index(
                    {
                        "globalinfo.itemsearchinfo": "text", 
                        "globalinfo.name": "text" 
                    }
                ); // schema level

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

This is my search query:

```
Item.find(
        { $text : { $search : "item" } }
    ).exec(function(err, items) {
```

The issue is that the query always returns no results!

I have one document in the model:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56781cb97ae92ff08b55d4f1"),
    "globalinfo" : {
        "friendlyurl" : "item-a",
        "dateadded" : ISODate("2015-12-21T15:37:29.591Z"),
        "itemsearchinfo" : "Woop lawn mower for rent!\nYou should use this space to describe the item in detail and make it appealing\nTo the renter write your stuff here.",
        "statuscss" : "na",
        "status" : "Not Available Yet",
        "locationlongitude" : null,
        "locationlatitude" : null,
        "locationpostcode" : "test",
        "locationtown" : "test",
        "locationline3" : "",
        "locationline2" : "",
        "locationline1" : "test",
        "termsapprove" : true,
        "price" : 3,
        "enddate" : ISODate("2015-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "startdate" : ISODate("2015-12-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "desc" : "\n                                    <h3>woop Lawn Mower for Rent! </h3>\n                                    <p>You should use this space to describe the item in detail and make it appealing to the renter <strong>Write your stuff here.</strong> \n                                </p>",
        "name" : "item A",
        "ownerobjectid" : "56781909155232b7871edb17"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The output of db.items.getIndexes():

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "whatplot_local_db.items"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "itemsearchinfo_text_name_text",
        "ns" : "whatplot_local_db.items",
        "background" : true,
        "weights" : {
            "itemsearchinfo" : 1,
            "name" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried re-indexing the collection?

Mongo command:

```
db.collection.reIndex();
```

The issue was with the way I was indexing. Using double quotes does not work:

```
itemSchema.index(
                    {
                        "globalinfo.itemsearchinfo": "text", 
                        "globalinfo.name": "text" 
                    }
                ); // schema level
```

However single quotes does:

```
itemSchema.index(
                    {
                        'globalinfo.itemsearchinfo': "text", 
                        'globalinfo.name': "text" 
                    }
                ); // schema level
```

Comment: I tried reIndexing it seemed to reIndex, but the search is still returning nothing.

Comment: whats the output of "db.items.getIndexes();"

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of db.items.getIndexes. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: If you search for 'item A'  instead of 'item' do you get a result?

Comment: As a test can you move or copy the name key value to the root of the document?  Reindex the collection and search again?  Im wondering if it has something to do with it being nested.   Were you required to put the key reference in quotes like that?   ie:  "globalinfo.itemsearchinfo": "text", "globalinfo.name": "text"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98586/discussion-between-cookiejest-and-jared).

Comment: The issue was to do with the nested name. using double quotes did not work. Using single quotes did!ie: 'globalinfo.itemsearchinfo': "text", 'globalinfo.name': "text"

Comment: @Cookiejest That doesn't make sense as there's no difference in using single quotes vs. double quotes. Must've been something else.

Comment: I tested it and that's what was making a difference.